# trying to understand my error in my pig java game

Tags: java

I am working on my final project for my intro to java class and i am having a hard time understanding the errors in my project and why it will not run if you could tell me why i would greatly appreciate it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner scanner1;

int dice, dice2;
int pScore, cScore = 0;
int pTotalScore = 0;
int cTotalScore = 0;
final int maxScore = 750;
String input = "R";
String input2 = "R";
char repeat;
Random randomNumbers = new Random();

System.out.println("Welcome to Our version of the dice game Pig");
System.out.println("Here are the instructions");
System.out.println("On a turn, the player or computer rolls the die repeatedly");
System.out.println("Until either a 1,7,12, or 17 is rolled");
System.out.println("or the player or computer holds");
System.out.println("If a 1,7,12, or 17  is rolled, that player's turn ends");
System.out.println("and no points are earned");
System.out.println("If the player chooses to hold, all of the points rolled during");
System.out.println("that turn are added to his or her score.");
System.out.println("First player to 750 points or more WINS!");

System.out.print("\nPlease enter your name: ");
scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
String pName = scanner1.nextLine();
System.out.print("\nI Hope You have fun," + pName);



do { // run at least once. Start of loop
    dice = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("%s you rolled a %d %n", pName, dice);

    if (dice == 1 || dice == 7 || dice == 12 || dice == 17) // if these numbers, end
    {
        pScore = 0;
        System.out.println("Turn over.");
        System.out.println(" " + pName + " total is " + pScore + " ");
        break;
    } else {    // else ask for re-roll
        pScore = dice;
        pTotalScore += pScore;
        System.out.print(+pScore + " Your turn total is " + pTotalScore + " ");
        System.out.print("Enter (R) to roll or (H)to hold: ");
        input = scanner1.nextLine();
        repeat = input.charAt(0);
    }

    if (repeat != 'R') { // if something other than R, end
        break;
    }

} while (pTotalScore < 750 || cTotalScore < 750); // allow repeat so long as scores are less than 750

    if (repeat == 'H') {
        System.out.println("Turn over.");
        System.out.print("Current score: " + pname + " has " + pTotalScore);
        System.out.println("The Computer has " + cTotalScore);
        break;

    }
    while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("R"));

    if (pTotalScore >= maxScore) {
        System.out.println("Your total Score is " + totalScore);
        System.out.println(+pname + "WINS!");
        break;
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("It is the Computer's turn.");
    do {

        dice2 = randomNumbers.nextInt(6) + 1;
        System.out.println("The Computer rolled: " + dice2);

        if (dice2 == 1 || dice2 == 7 || dice2 == 12 || dice2 == 17) {
            cScore = 0;
            System.out.print("Turn over");
            System.out.println("The Computer total is " + cTotalScore);
            break;
        } else {
            cScore = dice2;
            cTotalScore += cScore;
            System.out.print("The Computer's total is " + cTotalScore + " ");
            System.out.print("Enter (r) to Roll or (H)to Hold: ");
            input = keyboard.nextLine();
            repeat = input.charAt(0);
        }
        if (repeat == 'H') {
                System.out.println("Turn over");
                System.out.print("Current score:" + pName + " has " + pTotalScore);
                System.out.println(", The Computer has " + cTotalScore);
                break;
        }

    } while (input2.equalsIgnoreCase("R"));
    if (cTotalScore >= maxScore) {
       System.out.println("The Computer's score is " + cTotalScore + "\n");
        System.out.println("The Computer wins!!!!");
        System.out.printl("Run The uprisng has begun!!!!!!");
        break;
    }
```

Final3.java:112: error: reached end of file while parsing } ^ 1 error

now the problem is i get the error basically means im missing a } but i cant see  where it would be nd no matter where i put it it still says

Final3.java:112: error: reached end of file while parsing } ^ 1 error

Comment: What is this supposed to do `while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("R"));` ?

Comment: to ignore if you put r or R

Comment: To solve the error "error: reached end of file while parsing } ^ 1 error" you just put one `}` at the end of your file. Done! But your code is riddled with errors that stop it from compiling. You're referring to the non-existing variables `pname`, `keyboard` and `totalScore` and to the non-existing function `System.printl`. Please clean up your code before posting it here.

Comment: I suggest you take time to correctly indent your code, some problems then may be obvious even without our help!

Answer (score 0):

You have one while loop that does nothing - `while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("R"));` - and you didn't close your main method. Add `}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Add a closing brace "}" in the end.I hope this will solve your purpose.